# Reverse array after space using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

I have an array which I want to reverse like

> ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];

I want to reverse it like this

> ["I", " ", "e", "v", "o", "l", " ", "h", "t", "r", "a", "E"]

The problem is I can reverse it using `array.slice().reverse();` but it reverses the whole array and I want to reverse after where is space.

Comment: What about splitting first on the space character, then splitting each string into chars and reversing it, then join the whole thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, some dirty solution may be similar to this one:

```js
var sentence = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];
    
var reversed = sentence.join('').split(' ').map(word => word.split('').reverse().join('')).join(' ').split(''); 
    
console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it a string, then split and flatMap

```js
const arr = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];

const res = arr
              .join('')
              .split(' ')
              .flatMap(e => (e + ' ').split('').reverse())
              .slice(1);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a recursive approach and collect sub arrays and reverse this values.

```js
function swap(array, i = 0, temp = []) {
    if (i >= array.length || array[i] === ' ') {
       temp.forEach((v, j) => array[i - j - 1] = v);
       temp = [];
    } else {
        temp.push(array[i]);
    }
    if (i >= array.length) return array;
    return swap(array, i + 1, temp);
}

var array = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];

console.log(swap(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach by changing the value on the way back.

```js
function swap(array, i = 0, temp = []) {
    if (i >= array.length) return array;        
    swap(array, i + 1, array[i] === ' ' ? temp = [] : (temp.push(array[i]), temp));
    if (temp.length) array[i] = temp.shift();
    return array;
}

var array = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];

console.log(swap(array));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could either use the [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to loop through the array letter by letter (avoids creating multiple temporary arrays):

```js
var sentence = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];

var reversed = sentence.reduce((acc, letter) => {
    if (letter === ' ') {
        acc.result.push(letter);
        acc.insertIndex = acc.result.length;
    } else {
        acc.result.splice(acc.insertIndex, 0, letter);
    }
    return acc;
}, {result: [], insertIndex: 0});

console.log('reversed:', reversed.result);
```

Or use a combination of [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) & [Array.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) (creates multiple temporary arrays):

```js
var arr = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];
var sentence = arr.join(''); // "I love Earth"
var words = sentence.split(' '); // [ "I", "love", "Earth" ]
var reverseParts = words.map(w => w.split('').reverse().join('')); // [ "I", "evol", "htraE" ]
var reverseSentence = reverseParts.join(' '); // "I evol htraE"
var reversed = reverseSentence.split(''); // [ "I", " ", "e", "v", "o", "l", " ", "h", "t", "r", "a", "E" ]
console.log(reversed);
```

Certain lines could be combined, to make it shorter and still quite clear:

```js
var arr = ['I', ' ', 'l', 'o', 'v', 'e', ' ', 'E', 'a', 'r', 't', 'h'];
var words = arr.join('').split(' '); // [ "I", "love", "Earth" ]
var reverseParts = words.map(w => w.split('').reverse().join('')); // [ "I", "evol", "htraE" ]
var reversed = reverseParts.join(' ').split(''); // [ "I", " ", "e", "v", "o", "l", " ", "h", "t", "r", "a", "E" ]
console.log(reversed);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// without using extra array and any predefined methods
const reverseWords = (input = []) => {
    if(input.length === 0) {
        return [];
    }
    let j = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if(i == input.length - 1 || input[i] == " ") {
            let k = 0;
            let b = input[i] == " " ? 1: 0;
            while(j > k) {
                const temp = input[i - k - b];
                input [i - k - b] = input[i-j];
                input[i-j] = temp;
                j = j -1;
                k = k+1;
            }
            j = 0;
        }else{
            j = j +1;
        }
    }
    return input;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).